Hosting a .NET Minimal API in Azure Function
I want to integrate my minimal ASP.NET Core APIs into an Azure Function. While I can do this using the Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.Hosting 1.7.0 package in AWS, I'm currently unable to find a way to do the same in Azure.

Azure Functions have a specific implementation method. Have a look at the Build Serverless APIs with Azure Functions training module, or the Quickstart: Create your first C# function in Azure using Visual Studio.

Thanks fo the answer,  but i don't want to use the HTTP trigger for every route.
for example AWS documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/it_it/lambda/latest/dg/csharp-package-asp.html.
Also AWS have Lambda with HTTP Trigger but in AWS i can host a WEB Api in Lambda, i'm looking for something similiar in Azure.

I successfully created and deployed minimal ASP.NET Core APIs into an Azure Function app without any Issues.
I referred this github repo for code.
Function1.cs:
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
namespace RestFuncApp
{
    public static class Function1
    {   
        public static readonly List<Task> Items = new List<Task>();
        [FunctionName("CreateTask")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> CreateTask(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous,
                "post", Route = "task")]
            HttpRequest req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("Creating a new Task list item");
            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            var input = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TaskCreateModel>(requestBody);

            var task = new Task() { TaskDescription = input.TaskDescription };
            Items.Add(task);
            return new OkObjectResult(task);
        }
        [FunctionName("GetAllTasks")]
        public static IActionResult GetAllTasks(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous,
                "get", Route = "task")]
            HttpRequest req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("Getting Task list items");
            return new OkObjectResult(Items);
        }
        [FunctionName("GetTaskById")]
        public static IActionResult GetTaskById(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous,
                "get", Route = "task/{id}")]
            HttpRequest req,
            TraceWriter log, string id)
        {
            var task = Items.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == id);
            if (task == null)
            {
                return new NotFoundResult();
            }
            return new OkObjectResult(task);
        }
        [FunctionName("UpdateTask")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> UpdateTask(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous,
                "put", Route = "task/{id}")]
            HttpRequest req,
            TraceWriter log, string id)
        {
            var task = Items.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == id);
            if (task == null)
            {
                return new NotFoundResult();
            }
            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            var updated = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TaskUpdateModel>(requestBody);
            task.IsCompleted = updated.IsCompleted;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(updated.TaskDescription))
            {
                task.TaskDescription = updated.TaskDescription;
            }
            return new OkObjectResult(task);
        }
        [FunctionName("DeleteTask")]
        public static IActionResult DeleteTask(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, 
                "delete", Route = "task/{id}")]
            HttpRequest req,
            TraceWriter log, string id)
        {
            var task = Items.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == id);
            if (task == null)
            {
                return new NotFoundResult();
            }
            Items.Remove(task);
            return new OkResult();
        }
    }
}

Model.cs:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
namespace RestFuncApp
{
    public class Task
    {
        public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");
        public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
        public string TaskDescription { get; set; }
        public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }
    }
    public class TaskCreateModel
    {
        public string TaskDescription { get; set; }
    }
    public class TaskUpdateModel
    {
        public string TaskDescription { get; set; }
        public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }
    }
}


Right Click on Function app in solution Explorer -> Publish -> Azure -> Azure Function App (Windows) ->Select your App -> Finish.





Azure Function Output:



thanks for your response but in your code i c'ant see the tipically routing of minimal APi
eg :
app.MapGet("/hello", () => "Hello World!")
